# How to set primary Key column name when two or more foreign keys are used?

Tags: mysql

```
create table teach_enroll(

instructor_id varchar(64) not null,
class_id varchar(64)not null,
course_id varchar(64)not null,
student_id varchar(64) not null,
foreign key (instructor_id) references instructor(id),
foreign key (class_id) references class(id),
foreign key(course_id)references course_type(id),
foreign key (student_id)references student(id),

CONSTRAINT ENROLL_ID primary key (class_id,course_id,student_id) 

);

select * from teach_enroll;
```

I am trying to name my primary key column as ENROLL_ID but the constraint keyword is not helping when I query select * from teach_enroll I get only instructor_id,class_id,course_id,student_id in separate columns but I cannot see the primary key column :)

Comment: I want to use the above primary key as a foreign key in another table so how can I do that if I do not know the column name? Thanks

Comment: Your primary key consists of **three (3)** columns, not a single column, because that is the way you defined it. This means that the *combination* of those three column must be unique for each row in the table although any given column defined as the key may not be. You cannot apply a single name to three columns.

Comment: `foreign key (a, b, c) references foo(x, y, z)` ; Just as you specify three columns in the primary key, you specify three columns in the foreign key.

Comment: To allow naming of a PRIMARY KEY constraint, and for defining a PRIMARY KEY constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax: Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_primarykey.asp

Comment: Even if you name the primary key constraint, that doesn't create a column or allow you to reference it as if it were a column (by that constrain's name). Just. Use. All. Three. Column. Names. (Just like you did in defining the primary key.)

Comment: It's not clear what you expect here, my guess is you think FKs automatically pull or push data from the tables that the FK is in. They don't , you need to join the tables. NB FKs are primarily for referential integrity,

Answer (score 2):

Your primary key consists of three (3) columns, not a single column, because that is the way you defined it. This means that the combination of those three column must be unique for each row in the table although any given column defined as the key may not be. You cannot apply a single name to three columns.

This means that your foreign key constraint will name all 3 columns. Assuming the column names are the same in both tables, then:

```SQL
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (class_id,course_id,student_id)
    REFERENCES teach_enroll(class_id,course_id,student_id)
```